# SQLAlchemy trying to access a table in the wrong database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cherrypy

We use CherryPy and SQLAlchemy to build our web app and everything was fine until we tested with 2 concurrent users - then things started to go wrong! Not very good for a web app so I'd be very appreciative if anyone could shine some light on this.

**TL;DR**

We're getting the following error about 10% of the time when two users are using our site (but accessing different databases) at the same time:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'test_one.other_child_entity' doesn't exist")
```

This table is not present in that database so the error makes sense but the problem is that SQLAlchemy shouldn't be looking for the table in that database.

I have reproduced the error in an example here https://gist.github.com/1729817

**Explanation**

We're developing an application that is very dynamic and is based on the `entity_name` pattern found at http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/EntityName

We've since grown that idea so that it stores entities in different databases depending on what user you're logged in as. This is because each user in the system has their own database and can create their own entities (tables). To do this we extend a base entity for each database and then extend that new entity for each additional entity they create in their database.

When the app starts we create a dictionary containing the engine, metadata, classes and tables of all these databases and reflect all of the metadata. When a user logs in they get access to one.

When two users are accessing the site at the same time something is going wrong and SQLAlchemy ends up looking for tables in the wrong database. I guess this is to do with threading but as far as I can see we are following all the rules when it comes to sessions (CP and SQLA), engines, metadata, tables and mappers.

If anyone could give my example (https://gist.github.com/1729817) a quick glance over and point out any glaring problems that would be great.

**Update**

I can fix the problem by changing the code to use my own custom session router like so:

```
# Thank you zzzeek (http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/)
class RoutingSession(Session):
    def get_bind(self, mapper = None, clause = None):
        return databases[cherrypy.session.get('database')]['engine']
```

And then:

```
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush = True, autocommit = False, class_ = RoutingSession))
```

So just hard-coding it to return the engine that's linked to the database that's set in the session. This is great news but now I want to know why my original code didn't work. Either I'm doing it wrong or the following code is not completely safe:

```
# Before each request (but after the session tool)
def before_request_body():
    if cherrypy.session.get('logged_in', None) is True:
        # Configure the DB session for this thread to point to the correct DB
        Session.configure(bind = databases[cherrypy.session.get('database')]['engine'])
```

I guess that the binding that's happening here was being overwritten by the user in the other thread which is strange because I thought `scoped_session` was all about thread-safety?